# Full width nav bar for my website

Tags: html, css

I need some help. I have a website and I want to make some changes, but I don't know how. I read other questions here, but they didn't help. This is my website: http://www.bijuterii-din-inox.ro.

I want my nav bar to be the full width of the page. Can you please give me a hand!?  Thanks.

This is my css:

```
#top_nav {
    padding: 0 2px;
}

#top_nav ul {
    display: block;
    height: 43px;
}

#top_nav ul li i,
#top_nav ul li b {
    display: none;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#top_nav ul li a {
    float: left;
    height: 43px;
    line-height: 43px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#top_nav ul li.first a {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#top_nav ul li.last,
#top_nav ul li.single {
    background: none;
}

#top_nav ul li.single a {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: please append the HTML for this

Comment: Without the html it's hard to help you out. If possible, create a jsFiddle

Comment: I dont know how to append the html, this is my website, is this any help? www.bijuterii-din-inox.ro

Comment: Open the source code of your page, copy the HTML of all items that are addressed in your CSS- the navigation and all relevant wrappers. Click on **edit** under your Question, paste the html in the editor, select the new html/text in the editor and press the **code** button.

Answer (score 1):

use `width:100%` for the nav bar..!!

```
#top_nav {
width:100%;
padding: 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: @user3416680 post your html code in the question..!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change a bit more the styles, but below I paste some styles which will work better:

```
.hd_wide,.doc4,#top_nav ul{
 width:100% !important;
}

.doc4{
  font-size:1em !important;
  margin-left:0px !important;
  margin-right:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I edited the styles a bit more, please try with this. Remember to put them at the end of the CSS file, now it does not matter because they are as !important, but if not they could be replaced if you  keep old styles.

Comment: Sory.Still not working. Mabe i didn't explain very well, my english is not very good.I whant the navigation bar(only the blue bar) to be the full width of the page

Comment: don't worry I am from Uruguay and speak spanish too, and maybe we are not understanding ourselves lol. Please rephase you requirement or maybe I could send you a screenshot what is that I see with my changes.